# Angular select preselect doesn't work reliably

Tags: html, angular

I have got this select in my component:

```
<select class="vstatus-select" 
    [(ngModel)]="rezept.kunde.versichertenstatus1.kennung" 
    name="kunde_vstatus1"
    (focus)="vselect_focus(1)" 
    (change)="vselect_focusout(1)">
  <option *ngFor="let vstatus of versichertenstatus1"
      [ngValue]="vstatus.kennung">
    {{vstatus.kennung}}
  </option>
</select>
```

When I initially start the tool or reopen it, the preselected value is displayed properly.
But after setting an existing `rezept` object with exactly the same `kunde.versicherungsstatus`-values there is nothing shown inside the select-box. Until I select a value.

Any Ideas how I can display the "new" `kunde.versicherungsstatus`-values after changing them?

If that matters, I have got a share-service, which is called in the change like that:

```
constructor(private rezeptshareservice:RezeptShareService) {}

editRezept() {
  this.rezeptshareservice.rezept = this.rezept;
}
```

The function `editRezept()` is called on a Buttonclick.

And in the `EingabeComponent` like that:

```
constructor(private listsservice:ListsService)
  this.rezept = rezeptShareService.rezept;
}
```

`versichertenstatus` is a very simple interface:

```
export interface IVersichertenstatus{
    name: string;
    kennung: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you share versichertenstatus1 data model?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz of this ?

Otherwize, I think rezept.kunde.versichertenstatus1.kennung does not match a value in versichertenstatus1.

Comment: stackblitz would be very uncomfortable as I'm calling my local API. The versichertenstatus is previously selected from that select.

Comment: Where you are setting an existing rezept object with exactly the same kunde.versicherungsstatus- in the code?

Comment: I am sharing it in the Service. in editRezept() the existing one is getting shared to the eingabeComponent where i want to edit it.